# TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object - Typescript & Next.js

Tags: typescript, object, next.js, typescript-typings, next-auth

[photo of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQSIV.png)

I'm trying to render a button that will allow me to have login functionality. I am using Typescript and NextAuth. I have added a file for auth typings to try and solve the problem but for some reason, I am not able to use `Object` here with these map parameters.

At this instance, I have places the `provider` type as `any`. There's no error in the code editor but on the DOM, the type error still persists.

```
import { getProviders, signIn } from 'next-auth/react'
function Login({ providers }) {
return (
<div>
    <img className='w-52 mb-5' src="https://links.papareact.com/9xl" alt="Spotify logo at sign-in" />

    {Object.values(providers).map((provider:any) => (
        <div key={provider.name}>
            <button>Login with {provider.name}</button>
        </div>
    ))}
</div>
);
}

export default Login;

export async function getServerSideProps() {
const providers = await getProviders(); 

return {
    props: {
        providers,
    },
};
}
```

At this instance, I removed the type for `provider` and the code editor yields an error for `provider.name` that states "Property 'name' does not exist on type 'unknown'."

```
import { getProviders, signIn } from 'next-auth/react'
function Login({ providers }) {
return (
<div>
    <img className='w-52 mb-5' src="https://links.papareact.com/9xl" alt="Spotify logo at sign-in" />

    {Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
        <div key={provider.name}>
            <button>Login with {provider.name}</button>
        </div>
    ))}
</div>
);
}

export default Login;

export async function getServerSideProps() {
const providers = await getProviders(); 

return {
    props: {
        providers,
    },
};
}
```

Here's my typings file:

```
export interface Providers {
provider: string;
name: string;
_id: string;  
}
```

I have tried a few things to try and solve the error. I am new to Typescript and this is my first time using NextAuth so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Is `getProviders()` returning the expected `providers` object?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you can use `next`'s built in `InferGetServerSideProps` to infer the types from next-auth and save yourself some work.

Check out this example:

```js
import { getProviders, signIn } from 'next-auth/react'
import { InferGetServerSidePropsType } from 'next'

export default function SignIn({
  providers,
}: InferGetServerSidePropsType<typeof getServerSideProps>) {
  return (
    <>
      {Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
        <div key={provider.name}>
          <button onClick={() => signIn(provider.id)}>
            Sign in with {provider.name}
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  return {
    props: {
      providers: await getProviders(),
    },
  }
}
```

Since NextAuth.js is written in Typescript, it can automatically infer the types based off the return value of `getProviders()`